# The Proper Way To Handle Ajax Response Loading with js.erb files in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to Rails but I come from PHP, in which it was almost always the case that whenever I have an HTML AJAX response, I can always load it in a container(any element) using jquery's .load()

I did that with Rails too, but recently came into another approach: use .js.erb files. Use getScript() to a controller action, then the js.erb file will respond to the js (ajax) request, the do the loading in the .js.erb file.

given general.js:

```
$.getScript(url, function(){});
```

given index.js.erb:

```
$('#products').html("<%= escape_javascript(render_cell :products, :index, {:products => @products})%>");
```

but this appears to be quite repetitive when I can do the loading in general.js! Fire an ajax request to this template that a controller has and load that in a container(I can use jquery .load()'s selector to just select the elements I want, and I can use an application_controller condition to not render the layout):

```
<ul>
<%= render_cell :products, :index, {:products => @products} %>
</ul>
```

Is there any way I can make more effective use of .js.erb files in this case?

Note: I had to use the 2nd approach because I am using twitter-bootstrap tabs. I initially used the first approach but I think the 2nd way is more "the Rails way". This is a learning project so why not? XD

Comment: I personally normally return JSON objects from AJAX requests and just handle them with client JS. This doesn't really answer your question though. :D

Comment: so if you're expecting an HTML response, there may not be a need for .js.erb files, right? I mean, it falls back to the html.erb views if it can't find any js.erb views, right?